# Sailsjs has a 'prod' grunt task, why not a 'dev' task?

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I want to create a file called `config.js` for the client end of my app, but it should be based on the environment. I've successfully done this for production using the `tasks/register/prod.js` file, but sailsjs does not seem to have an equivalent `dev.js` file.

I also can't find much information about this, so I'm hoping there is a standard workaround I'm just not thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why I found it so confusing, or why I never opened the `README.md` (duh!) in `tasks/`, but dev stuff goes in the `default` task (`tasks/register/default.js`).

ANSWER: README's are named as such for a very good reason.